# How to show weekly cumulative data in react js highchart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I have highchart with daily data but I want to show as weekly cumulative in one day of each week or each month. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataGrouping` feature for Highstock:

```
series: [{
    dataGrouping: {
        forced: true,
        approximation: "sum",
        units: [
            [
                'week',
                [1]
            ],
            [
                'month',
                [1]
            ]
        ]
    },
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b6u2Lfa8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping